# how to join SQL with 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I'm trying to study `SQL`.

I have a problem with `JOIN`

I want to display `ref_id, pro_name, class_name` but I couldn't.

I find **EFFICIENT** solution.

**MY QUERY (DOESN'T WORK)**

```
SELECT
  ref_id, pro_name, class_name
FROM
  RC, RP, PP, LP
WHERE
  RC.ref_id = RP.ref_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using commas be `CROSS JOIN`

You could use `JOIN` to instead of commas

like this.

```
SELECT
  RP.ref_id, PP.pro_name, LP.class_name
FROM
  RP
LEFT JOIN RC ON RC.ref_id = RP.ref_id
LEFT JOIN PP ON PP.pro_id = RP.pro_id
LEFT JOIN LP ON LP.lec_id = RP.lec_id
```

Comment: @zynkn It's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.

You would seem to want:

```
select rp.pro_id, pp.pro_name, lp.class_name
from rp left join
     pp
     on rp.pro_id = pp.pro_id left join
     lp
     on rp.lec_id = lp.lec_id;
```

Note the use of `left join`.  This ensure that all rows are in the result set, even when one or the other joins doesn't find a matching record.

From what I can see, the table `rc` is not needed to answer this specific question.